# How do I associate a Steam game with a separate, non-Steam install?

Tags: steam

I just bought the Humble Indie Bundle V and I installed the games direct from the downloaded exe's. Today I noticed that there are Steam codes for all of these, which is pretty awesome. However, after activating my Steam codes, it doesn't acknolwedge that the games are already installed. I added them as non-Steam games, hoping it'd recognize that these games were some of the same ones already in my library but no dice. Do I just have to uninstall them all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AS far as I am aware, the Steam versions are different. Your best bet is to reinstall through Steam.

Comment: That really sucks. Some of these took a while to download.

Comment: @Zelbinian you can try starting the download, quit Steam, put the respective DRM free files into the steamapps\common's subfolder and restart Steam. It _may_ notice the data files don't have to be redownloaded and only [waste time downloading DirectX a few times](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30393/88)...

Comment: I accepted because the problem was solved. No use letting people waste time answering a question that isn't a problem anymore!

Comment: Ive had this issue with origin, as i have Command and Conquer 4 on steam. Origin's fine with that, but still wants me to download it for Origin. Also @Zommuter you dont need to quit steam, as long as you start the download with the files in place, steam should say "calculating pre found game files" (or something like that)

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza there's no reason to not accept a solving answer as soon as it appears. Should an even better answer show up later, it can a) still be re-accepted and b) might receive enough upvotes to show up directly following the accepted answer

Comment: @Zommuter as I said, it's customary, at least on other SE sites. I've read similar messages to mine at least a dozen times. But anyway. The usual reason given is that it may discourage other people from answering.

Comment: @Adriano the intention of marking an answer as accepted _is_ discouraging people from giving answers that add no further value. And to work as an indication for those who don't have the time to answer all questions they could, so they answer a question that wouldn't only benefit from their additional answer but from an answer at all. Of course this can go wrong and, as you suggest, discourage great answers which might actually prove the accepted answer inferior... But I'm afraid there is no perfect solution and IMHO it's better to accept an answer soon than to later forget accepting at all

Comment: (cont. Personally, I would have accepted your better elaborated answer, as you can see from the coincidence (also in posting time) with what I [commented on this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72609/how-do-i-associate-a-steam-game-with-a-separate-non-steam-install/72610#comment100633_72610))

Answer (score 13):

A quick search yields [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1908874.html). In particular, the last answer might help you:

> > As far as what I'm asking about, it isn't the account I'm trying to
> >     associate, it's the software. I'm wondering if there is a way to get
> >     the Steam program to acknowledge my copy of STO that was not installed
> >     through Steam short of the 'Add Non-Steam Game' option or reinstalling
> >     via Steam, since I also have it through Steam now.
>
> You can start the install in steam, then stop the download, close
>   steam completely, copy or move the STO folders into the steam
>   directory. Finally launch steam and validate files for STO, steam
>   should recognise everything, it might download a file or 2 but it
>   won't be much.
>
> Thats what I did for the steam version of Fallout 3 goty and
>   everything went smoothly (had the base game only and bought the
>   package on sale for a few bucks, copied the FO3 files to steam and
>   verified, saved myself a few hours download and have all the usual
>   steam features as a bonus).

I suppose it can't hurt to try.

Comment: You don't actually have to start the download first anymore. Recently (not sure exactly when) Steam added a step in the download game dialog which checks for existing files first. I just did this last night with Splinter Cell: Conviction and noticed the new step.