# How do I find the ID for a game on Steam?

Tags: steam

Every game on Steam has a different Game ID (also known as App ID). For instance, looking on my own computer, *Portal* has an ID of `400`, and *FTL: Faster Than Light* is `212680`.

How do I find this ID for a specific game on Steam?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Go to the game's store page and check the URL. The last number in the URL is the application ID. All the store URLs are in format `store.steampowered.com/app/APPID`, so for Wasteland 2, the URL is `http://store.steampowered.com/app/240760/`, and appID 240760.

[image: store.steampowered.com/app/240760/]

Another reliable way is to search for the program on [steamdb](http://steamdb.info), which will show you the info for games removed from the store as well. The appid is clearly labelled in the search results.

Comment: What is this, an answer that has freehand circles and no upvotes? I shall rectify this injustice!

Comment: So simple, _Que magnifique!_ Thanks for also editing in the additional information such as a sample game URL and the screenshot.

Comment: This won't work for games that have been removed from the store, or games which have never had a store page *(which is a surprising number)*.  It also does not work for DLC or packages which do not have their own store page.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft good point, updated the answer

Comment: Works with community pages too, within Steam client if I go to CS:GO community page it shows `http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/` as the URI, 730 is the app-id for CS:GO and so I can run it from a console (on Linux) with `steam steam://run/730`.

Answer (score 7):

Many of the methods above work but I am going to show you an offline version. I am using Windows and uncertain if it works with other systems. If you head into your Steam directory and open SteamApps, and then open common. There you will find a list of games. Open your chosen folder and find "steam_appid". Open it, and it will show the ID in a text document.

Comment: many games lack that file steam_appid.txt

Comment: @SamWatkins Would you have any evidence to support that?

Comment: Not sure how to provide evidence to you. I have 395 games installed by steam, of which 88 have steam_appid.txt in the right place, one of those is an empty file.  31 more games have steam_appid.txt in a different location.  Only 30% of my games have any steam_appid.txt file anywhere in the installation.

Ok here is some evidence you might be able to check.  Neither Team Fortress 2 nor DOTA 2 (free games) have any steam_appid.txt (on Linux at least).

I can give you one or two windows games without steam_appid.txt if you don't believe me: Jolly Rover, and Cthulhu Saves the World.

Comment: `find ~/Games/steam/steamapps/common -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name 'Proton*' -ls | wc -l` => 
67 `find ~/Games/steam/steamapps/common -type f -name 'steam_appid.txt' -ls | wc -l => 14`. So 14 out of 67 games have a `steam_appid.txt` file.

Answer (score 5):

A list of all your installed steam apps and their appID's can be obtained easily with one line of BASH offline using grep, sed and awk to look at the appmanifest files in Steam/steamapps/(on Linux/Unix)

your path to /steamapps/ may vary if you install your games to a non default place.

```
grep -n "name" ~/Steam/steamapps/*.acf | sed -e 's/^.*_//;s/\.acf:.:/ /;s/name//;s/"//g;s/\t//g;s/ /-/' | awk -F"-" '{printf "%-40s %s\n", $2, $1}' | sort
```

Breakdown of what that one line of bash does:

1. grep for lines containing "name" in all the .acf files in steamapps/
   the lines it returns are the filepath/name of the .acf with the appID in them followed by our mathed grep pattern "name" and the name of the application.
2. sed to strip the line up to and including the "_" (leaving the appid), replace the tabs with a single space, remove the double quotes, remove the word "name", replace the first space after the id number with a "-" (a character that is not found in any game names)
3. awk with "-" set as the delimiter to print the columns formatted with the name of the game followed by the ID number
4. sort to alphabetize

Comment: Thanks for the linux solution, added that as an alias in my bashrc ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer for this in the Steam Support, however, **it requires you to be running both Steam and Windows**.

Taken from [*Steam Support: Finding the Application ID for a Steam Game*](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20141203102536/https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3729-WFJZ-4175):

> This process can also be used for Demos, Media, and other products on Steam:
>
> 1. Login to the Steam account
> 2. Go to your Library
> 3. Right click the installed game and choose "Create desktop shortcut"
> 4. Go to your Desktop and locate the new shortcut
> 5. Right-click on the shortcut and select Properties
> 6. Look at the target path for the number following `steam://rungameid/`. This number is the Application ID for the game.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is another solution that works on Linux (Ubuntu in this case) inspired by the answer by @Slobeck above.

```
$ find ~/Games/steam/steamapps/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.acf' -exec awk -F '"' '/"appid|name/{ printf $4 "|" } END { print "" }' {} \; | column -t -s '|' | sort -k 2
285820   Action Henk
290340   Armello
622020   ATV Drift & Tricks
308040   Back to Bed
637090   BATTLETECH
376770   Big Thinkers 1st Grade
376760   Big Thinkers Kindergarten
49520    Borderlands 2
261640   Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel
```

Substitute the path to your `steamapps` directory as appropriate, if you don't know where it is you can run this command to find it:

```
$ find ~ -type d | grep steamapps
```

I would be interested to know if this would work on Windows 10 with Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: The path will usually be `~/.steam/steam/steamapps` for native installations, and something else that I don't know for flatpack.

Comment: I found an old redit post that suggests it will be `~/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/data/Steam/steamapps/common/` for flatpack. Try `find ~/.var | grep steamapps`

Answer (score 0):

While [3ventic's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/149839/30879) is the easiest way, there is a way to do it which is fully offline and more garunteed than [Waddling Pig's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/150176/30879) (as not all games have that steam_appid file) however this will only work for games you have downloaded as this method has you look in the steamapps folder.

in the steamapps folder you'll see a bunch of `appmanifest_######.acf` files, the # are the app id for the game, but also other information such as where the game's directory is and it's name. using Notepad++

1. Open the "Find in Files" dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>
2. in "Find What" enter the name of the game
3. in "Filter" put in `*.acf`
4. in "Directory" put in the path to the steampps folder
5. untick "In all Sub folders"
6. Click "Find in Files"

and quickly you should get a result with the highlighted line of the file being the game name, verify this and look at the filename of the .acf file and the number in the name is your id. you can use any other program you are familiar with if it can

- search for text in files in a specified directory
- can be filtered to only look at .acf files and/or just the steamapps directory (as it can slow right down if your also searching every file in the common directory which is where the games are normally downloaded too)

this method also has the extra benefit in that if you are looking for where the game files are, the .acf file will have that listed in there too (i have came across the rare instances where game folders in common aren't intuitive to the game they actually are)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, you can try using this Batch Script to get your Run Game ID.
It takes files from %appdata% start menu folder, duplicates, and changes the file extension from ".URL" to ".TXT" Then it read out the output and filter it.

```
@echo off

REM Set up the Variable
set GameName=Beat Saber
set TempFile=TempFile

REM Prepare for trouble, and make it double
copy "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Steam\%GameName%.url" "%TEMP%\%TempFile%.txt" 
pushd %TEMP%


REM did it work? 
IF EXIST "%TempFile%.txt" (
echo Temp file is created!
) ELSE (
echo Uh Oh Stinky!
)

REM read the Temp file and filter the output
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`findstr /I "rungameid" .\%TempFile%.txt`) DO (
SET num=%%F
)
set id=%num:~22,28%  

REM did it work?
Echo Your Run Game Id is %id%   

REM Lets commit Gammer Moment
start steam://rungameid/%id%

REM clean up the mess
del /f %TempFile%.txt

REM is it clean yet?
IF EXIST "%TempFile%.txt" (
echo Temp File exists
) ELSE (
echo Temp File is no more
)

REM enable for debugging
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

[Steamdb](https://steamdb.info/) is the best third party resource providing information about steam. It has a huge amount of information available. In order to find a `appid` using steamdb load the site and enter the game name in the search box and hit enter.

The returned results provide a list of games including the `appid`. You can click on the appropriate `appid` to visit the page for that game. Another handy feature is if you have the `appid` you can enter it in the search box and it will automatically load the page for that game.

Here is an example using [Sokobond (appid 290260)](https://steamdb.info/app/290260/)

[image: steamdb]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is new or not, but... I found a Steam client solution!

**Right click game -> Properties -> Updates -> App ID**

Yay!

Answer (score -1):

None of the above worked (at least easily),

(Just to be clear this works in Ubuntu Linux's Desktop)

One way from another post I read, ... is to make a shortcut on the desktop, and R. Click IT'S properties, and it is in the end of the "Commands:" Line One WILL find the AppID (rungameid).

ex's. (in my Shortcut)

#

Name: The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim.desktop

Command: steam steam://rungameid/72850

#

Therefore Elder Scrolls ... appid is 72850

Always trying to Help, Mark

Comment: I'm confused on how none of these worked "easily" for you.  The URL for Skyrim is https://store.steampowered.com/app/72850/The_Elder_Scrolls_V_Skyrim/.  That is indicative of the accepted answer.  What happened in your case?