# Viewing Non-owned Steam Game Achievements

Tags: steam, achievements

On the Steam store page for games, if the game has more than four achievements, it is possible to click "view all achievements" to view the global statistics and details for those achievements.

However, if the game has four or less than four achievements, there is no link to access these achievements. Very strange that Valve has done nothing about this (that is easily findable)

Is there a way to access this data without going through other profiles (a possibility mentioned [here](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/540742667319347691/))?

For convenience, the last game I saw that describes the problematic scenario is [*Voxelied*](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Game ID (if not, [see this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/149837/87186)), you can view your achievement list on

`https://steamcommunity.com/my/stats/<Game's ID>/achievements/`

or the global achievements list on

`https://steamcommunity.com/stats/<Game's ID>/achievements/`.

For example, Voxelized's achievements list can be found on https://steamcommunity.com/stats/344040/achievements/

Comment: ps. Voxelized is an "Asset Flip" and I advise against buying it in order to protect the integrity of Steam.

Comment: What do you mean by "Asset Flip" and protect the integrity of steam? Just curious :)

Comment: @Denelio an "Asset Flip" is a game that's made by combining premade assets, usually from the Unity Asset Store, usually for the sole intention of making a profit, rather than making a game. It damages the overall quality of Steam, damages the public image of Unity3d Engine, Unity Asset Store, Steam Greenlight and Indie developers in general.