# Steam App ID of a non-Steam game added to Steam in SteamOS on Steam Deck

Tags: steam, steam-deck, steam-os

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/386882/131033), I need to find a non-Steam game ID so I could locate its Proton prefix inside `/home/deck/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/compatdata/` in SteamOS on Steam Deck.

I can find the ID by grepping the `ps` output (`ps aux | grep "SteamLaunch AppId="`) while the game is running, and that ID is a correct value which I can use to locate the game's Proton prefix inside `compatdata`.

However, I cannot figure out where else I could get this value from? What is the hashing function that Steam uses to generate it? I tried the code from [the answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/386883/131033) in that thread that I linked, but it outputs a different value (*different from the one the game actually gets*).

Moreover, I did a simple experiment: added an executable as a non-Steam game, wrote down the ID it got, removed that game from Steam library, removed its Proton prefix, added the same executable under the same path as a non-Steam game again, and this time it got a different ID. So apparently there are more arguments (*probably a timestamp*) to that hashing function than just the path to executable and name/title (*that would also explain why the code from that answer outputs a different value*).

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting way to do this:

- Change the Controller Layout of the game at least once
- Go to /home/deck/.local/share/Steam/logs/console_log.txt (restart the Steam Deck if is not there)
- Look for a line mentioning your game that looks like this:

> [2024-02-12 20:30:40] Loaded Config for Local Selection Path for App ID 2691939340, Controller 15: /home/deck/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Steam Controller Configs/157949493/config/minecraft/controller_neptune.vdf

In this case, 2691939340 is the App ID.