# How to upload saves to Steam Cloud without having the game installed locally?

Tags: steam, macos, steam-cloud, geforce-now

I need to upload a save file to Steam Cloud for use on Geforce Now (that reads saves from Steam Cloud). The game won't install locally on my Mac, so I need to do it without installing the game. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: IDK if it'll work, but you can try to create the save data structure (PCGamingWiki should help) and then run Steam with the command-line option `cloud_sync_up - <appid>` from [unofficial Steam command-line docs on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/davispuh/6600880). Or just open a browser and enter `steam://open/console` (uses [Steam Browser Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol)), and enter the command in the new Console tab of the Steam client. Replace [the appid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149837/how-do-i-find-the-id-for-a-game-on-steam).

Answer (score 1):

Transferring saved data into Steam is a bit complicated, but its easy to follow:

- Get the appid of the game (check [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/149837/199843) for more information)
- Open a browser and go to steam://open/console (if it asks for confirmation, say Yes)
- Enter `cloud_sync_up [appid]`, where appid is the id you got before, and press enter
- Get your Steam3 id (go to [SteamRep](https://steamrep.com), enter your profile url and copy the number from `steam3ID: [U:1:THENUMBERHERE]`)
- Go to ~/Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata and open the folder that matches your Steam3 ID
- Open the folder that matches your appid
- Change the saved files as you wish
- Go back to the Steam console and enter `cloud_sync_up [appid]`

When transferring saved data macOS to Windows, please note that some games use different files that are incompatible between platforms (Saints Row 2 and CSGO/2 come to mind).